# PHP/SQL syntax: passing variable to SQL query

Tags: php, sql, variables, printf

I am getting tired trying to see what is wrong. I have two php. From the first I am sending a variable 'select1' (basically the id) to the second and than I want to update that record uploading a pdf file.

```
$id = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['select1'])) {
  $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['select1']);
}



if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    $my_upload->the_temp_file = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    $my_upload->the_file = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    $my_upload->http_error = $_FILES['upload']['error'];
    if ($my_upload->upload()) { // new name is an additional filename information, use this to rename the uploaded file
        mysql_query(sprintf("UPDATE sarcini1 SET file_name = '%s' WHERE id_sarcina = '%s'", $my_upload->file_copy, $id));
    }
}
```

If I put a line with a valid id, like:

```
$id = 14;
```

it is working. What I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: what's the error that you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to accept both post & get, then you should try something like the code below to retrieve the variable.

```
$var = 'select1';
if( isset( $_POST[$var] ) ) {
    $id = $_POST[$var];
} else if( isset( $_GET[$var] ) ) {
    $id = $_GET[$var];
} else {
    $id = -1;
}
```

Comment: Still not working. And trying to get a feedback using <?php echo $id;?> i get the right value....

Comment: The $id is still not recognized by the mysql_query(sprintf("UPDATE sarcini1 SET file_name = '%s' WHERE id_sarcina = '%s'", $my_upload->file_copy, $id));

Comment: I am not sure where you tried to `echo $id;` (assuming just before the call to mysql_query) so you're sure you actually get there. Also not sure if you get any error messages or any kind of output, if yes it may be useful to provide them.

Comment: As a side note, you probably should use mysqli extension instead of mysql (or ADOdb or PDO), and use bind variables instead of building the query with sprintf

Comment: Thank you for your time. So, I inserted an echo $id after your ideea and before   if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {..... bla, bla and it shows the right id.I found a free php code here [link](http://www.finalwebsites.com/snippets.php?id=7)and I intend to update some of my records uploading a pdf file (the copy of the invoice) and saving the name as file_name in *sarcini1* table.

Comment: If I provide a correct id (lets say *$id= 10*) it is working (uploading the file and saving the name) but if I pass the id from another php file it is not working. I guess is something wrong with:    *mysql_query(sprintf("UPDATE sarcini1 SET file_name = '%s' WHERE id_sarcina = '%s'", $my_upload->file_copy, $id));*

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by passing around it. In my above question I tried to insert a record with all data and than update it with the name of the uploaded pdf file based on record id. Now I am uploading the file, insert a record with only one data: the name of the pdf file and than I can update the record based on name of the pdf file. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are using both GET and POST at the same time. As far as I can see, this condition is not returning True

```
if (isset($_GET['select1']))
```

Edit: If you don't find any answer in above; maybe some more information/code can help getting to a solution.